# liferay portlet: access forbidden after time period for guest user

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I created a portlet on Liferay 6.1, JBoss 7 for guests.
It needs to work for the user even if he hasn't made an action for a long period of time.

Actual if I do something in my portlet and wait for about 10 minutes and then do something again (for example changing jsp by hitting a button), this error appears:
[image]

It's german, but it means: forbidden, you don't have the permission to access this ressource.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options that I can think of.
1) Increase the session time out.
2) Make an ajax request to your server to keep your session active.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I also found this to this topic: [link](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/44980817) It seems that their is no way to add a clean solution. I will try 1), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your problem... just some suggestions:

1. Are you sure your portlet has view permission for guest users? To verify login, and go to permission by clicking on icon placed in the upper-right corner.
2. Does you code deal with permission? (if "not", then ignore this point)

For your needs, don't forget that it's possible that your portlet can lose data in your guest session after timeout in any case.